# Rotate a GameObject with Touch

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have this code below and works in Keyboard, but does not works with touch.

```
Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;  float z = rot.eulerAngles.z;      
z-= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;   
rot =    Quaternion.Euler( 0, 0, z );   
transform.rotation = rot;
```

I need that code above works on touch, how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should read the Api for input of Unity Scripting http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

you could use the getTouch method to rotate the object
here the documentation

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

you can use the delta for draging or the Position for rotating the Object

so it would be like this not sure its working it should work with dragging

```
 if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
     Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
     z-=touchDeltaPosition.x * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;   
     rot =    Quaternion.Euler( 0, 0, z );   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be nearly the same as above but instead of the x axis which is the horizontal one we are using the y axis for the vertical one  this code  is also with dragging

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
     Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
Vector3 pos = transform.position; 
Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(0, touchDeltaPoition.y * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
pos += rot * velocity;
}
```